# How to filter json data by date range in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to filter the below json data by start date and end date, it should return the data between start date and end date, I tried to achieve using below code but I'm doing wrong something to filter. I'm new to front end technologies like Javascript and jquery, it would be appreciated if Someone can correct me what I'm doing wrong here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var product_data = [
                {
                    "productId": "12",
                    "productName": "ProductA",
                    "productPrice": "1562",
                    "ProductDateCreated": "2015-07-24T12:58:17.430Z",
                    "TotalProduct": 294
                },
                {
                    "productId": "13",
                    "productName": "ProductB",
                    "productPrice": "8545",
                    "TotalProduct": 294,
                    "ProductHits": {
                        "2015-08-01T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "productId": "14",
                    "productName": "ProductC",
                    "productPrice": "8654",
                    "TotalProduct": 78,
                    "ProductHits": {
                        "2015-08-10T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "productId": "15",
                    "productName": "ProductD",
                    "productPrice": "87456",
                    "TotalProduct": 878,
                    "ProductHits": {
                        "2015-05-12T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                }
            ];

            var startDate = "2015-08-04";
            var endDate = "2015-08-12";

            var resultProductData = product_data.filter(
                    function (a)
                    {
                        return (a.ProductHits) > startDate && (a.ProductHits) < endDate;
                    });
            console.log(resultProductData);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you compare strings. you have to compare dates. Solution: convert the strings to Date objects and compare them. EDIT: ProductHits is no string. it's an object. you have to convert all keys of this object and compare them one by one.

Comment: How to convert key as object?

Comment: first: tell me pls why there are spaces in your date strings after the colons?

Comment: second: tell me pls the rule for ProductHits. there are multiple entries (dates). have they all match the range or only one of them?

Comment: aaand (last one ;)). are you sure it shell be ProductHits and not ProductDateCreated ? In my opnion that would make more sense...

Comment: I don't know how that space got added, I removed the space in my post, Now you won't see space in dates. Regarding Multiple entries is for **Capturing the product hit on daily basis**.  For Example: Product Id 13 got hit on 2015-08-01, 2015-08-04 and 2015-08-12. If pass start date range as 2015-0-04 - it should return product id 13 also

Comment: yes..its ProductHits only not ProductDateCreated

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
        var startDate = new Date("2015-08-04");
        var endDate = new Date("2015-08-12");

        var resultProductData = product_data.filter(function (a) {
            var hitDates = a.ProductHits || {};
            // extract all date strings
            hitDates = Object.keys(hitDates);
            // convert strings to Date objcts
            hitDates = hitDates.map(function(date) { return new Date(date); });
            // filter this dates by startDate and endDate
            var hitDateMatches = hitDates.filter(function(date) { return date >= startDate && date <= endDate });
            // if there is more than 0 results keep it. if 0 then filter it away
            return hitDateMatches.length>0;
        });
        console.log(resultProductData);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nz1ahuw/

---

**UPDATE** as Ates Goral suggests in the comments the solution above can be optimized by using Array.protype.some:

```
        var startDate = new Date("2015-08-04");
        var endDate = new Date("2015-08-12");

        var resultProductData = product_data.filter(function (a) {
            var hitDates = a.ProductHits || {};
            // extract all date strings
            hitDates = Object.keys(hitDates);
            // improvement: use some. this is an improment because .map()
            // and .filter() are walking through all elements.
            // .some() stops this process if one item is found that returns true in the callback function and returns true for the whole expression
            hitDateMatchExists = hitDates.some(function(dateStr) {
                var date = new Date(dateStr);
                return date >= startDate && date <= endDate
            });
            return hitDateMatchExists;
        });
        console.log(resultProductData);
```

thank you for your good advice :)

Comment: You can also use `Array.prototype.some` as an optimization: `return Object.keys(a.ProductHits || {}).some(function (dateStr) { var date = new Date(dateStr); return date >= startDate && date <= endDate; });` (Terminates the iteration the moment there's a match.)

Comment: @AtesGoral good advice. Feel free to edit it into the post as an update block if you want. thank you :)

Comment: My pleasure. I didn't want to spoil the clarity of your original answer :)

Comment: @AtesGoral added your solution to the answer. I hope it is also clearly documented ;)

Comment: @Joshua K -  As per your code why date is showing less than one day. For example: As per code start date is "2015-08-4" but if I print this value it shows Mon Aug 03 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) and End date is showing Tue Aug 11 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)? Do you know why its taking one day less ?

Comment: @jquerybeginner that depends on your timezone. see the -0700 at the end of the date? 17:00:00 o'clock + 7 hours are midnight. If you want to vonvert the date to GMT +0 you can use `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()` and `Date.prototype.valueOf()`. but think about it: dows it matter? all dates are changed the same way and you compare them with greater and lower operators. so... it shouldn't matter ;)

Answer (score 18):

I could not get the above solutions to work. I found a slight modification to the approved answer [that worked for me here](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4v1fgb/filtering_json_array_by_date/) . The code snippet below got the job done.

```
var startDate = new Date("2015-08-04");
var endDate = new Date("2015-08-12");

var resultProductData = product_data.filter(a => {
  var date = new Date(a.ProductHits);
  return (date >= startDate && date <= endDate);
});
console.log(resultProductData)
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me without a doubt! @Seunope

Answer (score 3):

For you, the dates values need to be encapsulated as such eg. new Date(your date value)

Another approach is given using the following example as a guide:

https://jsfiddle.net/ladiv7/tb66ya67/

```js
/*Dummy Data, Courtesy of: https://www.generatedata.com/*/
var dataDates = [{
    "date": "Nov 28, 2017",
    "name": "Samuel A. Kidd",
    "email": "dui.nec@sapienimperdietornare.ca",
    "address": "944-343 Nec Avenue"
  },
  {
    "date": "May 20, 2015",
    "name": "Jenna R. Alston",
    "email": "semper.auctor.Mauris@acrisus.edu",
    "address": "5316 Mollis Av."
  },
  {
    "date": "Mar 11, 2018",
    "name": "Magee K. Mcfarland",
    "email": "Maecenas@egetmollis.co.uk",
    "address": "Ap #605-1298 Id Rd."
  },
  {
    "date": "Dec 9, 2016",
    "name": "Claudia V. Campbell",
    "email": "Donec@semegestas.ca",
    "address": "Ap #935-7909 Lectus Rd."
  },
  {
    "date": "Aug 4, 2015",
    "name": "Steven V. Reynolds",
    "email": "est.ac@ut.net",
    "address": "Ap #501-8119 Vel, Rd."
  },
  {
    "date": "Mar 25, 2019",
    "name": "Amy O. Bean",
    "email": "risus.quis.diam@adipiscingelitEtiam.org",
    "address": "1855 Euismod Ave"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jan 12, 2019",
    "name": "Quintessa H. Clay",
    "email": "arcu.Sed.eu@variusNam.net",
    "address": "P.O. Box 127, 812 Lobortis Rd."
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb 7, 2015",
    "name": "Marvin P. Golden",
    "email": "pellentesque@lobortistellusjusto.org",
    "address": "P.O. Box 936, 8921 Augue Av."
  },
  {
    "date": "Aug 4, 2015",
    "name": "Shay Z. Clayton",
    "email": "sem.egestas@maurisidsapien.org",
    "address": "5862 Pede St."
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb 12, 2015",
    "name": "Jin G. Jimenez",
    "email": "dictum.magna@parturientmontes.org",
    "address": "4310 Malesuada Av."
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb 10, 2017",
    "name": "Dawn R. Blackwell",
    "email": "risus.varius.orci@ipsumdolor.com",
    "address": "5585 Metus. St."
  },
  {
    "date": "Apr 28, 2015",
    "name": "Audra A. Gates",
    "email": "consectetuer.adipiscing@libero.ca",
    "address": "448-332 Iaculis Ave"
  },
  {
    "date": "May 6, 2018",
    "name": "Gloria K. Dodson",
    "email": "mauris.Integer.sem@purusinmolestie.co.uk",
    "address": "564-3879 Vel, St."
  },
  {
    "date": "Jan 1, 2015",
    "name": "Inga I. Vinson",
    "email": "Donec@enimnec.net",
    "address": "320-4632 Lacus. Road"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jul 21, 2015",
    "name": "Berk M. Owen",
    "email": "eros@mi.co.uk",
    "address": "727 Bibendum Ave"
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb 27, 2016",
    "name": "Jessica C. Thompson",
    "email": "Donec@anteNunc.com",
    "address": "P.O. Box 903, 2394 A, St."
  }
];



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.datepicker').datepicker(); //Activates the datepicker Materialize CSS element

  preview_json(dataDates, $("#view_rawData")); //show the original data on the screen
  $("#count_RawData").html("(" + dataDates.length + ")");

  $("#filter-button").click(function(e) {

    console.log("Hello world");

    //Gets the form data in a unified manner
    var getFormData = {
      dates: {
        start: $("#date_from").val(),
        end: $("#date_to").val()
      }
    };

    //Function to filter the result
    var filteredData = dateFilterer(dataDates, getFormData.dates.start, getFormData.dates.end);
    preview_json(filteredData.finalValues, $("#view_filteredData")); //show the final result on the screen
    $("#count_FilteredData").html("(" + filteredData.finalValues.length + ")");

  });


});


//Filter function to ensure that the final result set is within a particular range
function dateFilterer(sourceValues, startDate, endDate) {

  /*Curtosy of the tutorial found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp*/
  function filterFunction_dates(sourceValue) {

    //Aim: To test if the tested date is valid within a particular range
    var rangeAcceptance = {
      minValid: new Date(sourceValue.date) >= new Date(startDate),
      maxValid: new Date(sourceValue.date) <= new Date(endDate)
    };

    var acceptanceResult; //boolean to determine if the relevant range specified is valid

    if (startDate != "" && endDate != "") {

      acceptanceResult = (rangeAcceptance.minValid && rangeAcceptance.maxValid);

    } else if (startDate != "") {

      acceptanceResult = rangeAcceptance.minValid;

    } else if (endDate != "") {

      acceptanceResult = rangeAcceptance.maxValid;

    } else {

      acceptanceResult = (1 == 1); //show all results if no specific range has been selected

    }

    return (acceptanceResult);

  }

  /*console.log({

    originalValues: sourceValues,
    finalValues: sourceValues.filter(filterFunction_dates),
    "time of filter": new Date()

  });*/

  //Return the data for display
  return ({

    originalValues: sourceValues,
    finalValues: sourceValues.filter(filterFunction_dates)

  });

}



//Aim: To make the dates into something that the Range filter function can work with
function normalize_date(fieldValue) {

  var monthPossibilities = {
    longStructure: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    shortStructure: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
  }; //To store what the month values could possibly be for returning their relevant index number

  var datePartitions = fieldValue.split(", ");
  var year = datePartitions[1];
  var month = datePartitions[0].substring(0, 3); //first three characters of section 1

  if (monthPossibilities.longStructure.indexOf(month) > -1) {

    month = (monthPossibilities.longStructure.indexOf(month) + 1).toString(); //Increments by one to give the actual month number

  } else if (monthPossibilities.shortStructure.indexOf(month) > -1) {

    month = (monthPossibilities.shortStructure.indexOf(month) + 1).toString();

  } else {

    month = "";

  }

  //Aim: Add that customary zero to prepend the date value
  if ((month.length < 2) && (month.length > 0)) {

    month = "0" + month;

  }

  var day = datePartitions[0].slice(-2); //last two characters of section 1    
  var finalResult = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

  return (finalResult);

}




//Aim: Display json in a nicely formatted way
function preview_json(data, target) {

  /*Curtosy of fellow fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/unLSJ/*/
  var library = {};

  library.json = {
    replacer: function(match, pIndent, pKey, pVal, pEnd) {
      var key = '<span class=json-key>';
      var val = '<span class=json-value>';
      var str = '<span class=json-string>';
      var r = pIndent || '';
      if (pKey)
        r = r + key + pKey.replace(/[": ]/g, '') + '</span>: ';
      if (pVal)
        r = r + (pVal[0] == '"' ? str : val) + pVal + '</span>';
      return r + (pEnd || '');
    },
    prettyPrint: function(obj) {
      var jsonLine = /^( *)("[\w]+": )?("[^"]*"|[\w.+-]*)?([,[{])?$/mg;
      return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 3)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\\"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(jsonLine, library.json.replacer);
    }
  };

  //Show json in desired target
  target.html(library.json.prettyPrint(data));

}
```

```css
#count_RawData {
  color: #89cbfa;
}

#view_rawData,
#view_filteredData {
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 700px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

#count_FilteredData {
  color: #498e88;
}

#filter-button {
  width: 100%;
}

#filter_section {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  /* background-color: #f1f1f1; */
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}


/*Curtosy of the fellow fiddler's code: http://jsfiddle.net/unLSJ/*/

pre {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.json-key {
  color: brown;
}

.json-value {
  color: navy;
}

.json-string {
  color: olive;
}


/*Update the scrollbar*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(132, 144, 154);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <title>JSON - Date Range Filter Concept</title>

  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">JSON Date Range Filter</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="sidenav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" data-target="nav-mobile" class="sidenav-trigger">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="section">

      <!--   Raw Data Section   -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h4 class="center">Raw Data <small id="count_RawData">(0)</small></h4>
            <pre id="view_rawData" class="light">
              Your raw data will be previewed here
            </pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Filter Form-->
      <div class="row center" id="filter_section">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="date_from" type="text" placeholder="From" class="datepicker">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="date_to" type="text" placeholder="To" class="datepicker">
        </div>
        <button id="filter-button" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light">Filtra</button>
      </div>

      <!--   Filtered Data Section   -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h4 class="center">Filtered Data <small id="count_FilteredData">(0)</small></h4>
            <pre id="view_filteredData" class="light">
              Your final data will be previewed here
            </pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <br><br>
  </div>

</body>

</html>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/js/init.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the example ^

Comment: Did you want the iframe, or did you just want to link to the Fiddle? Iframes don't work here (thankfully).

Comment: My bad.. thanks for the intel. Just updated the post for more clarity. Hope it helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do filter between `two` dates. I am filtering data from `yesterday` to `last7Days`.

```
public itemFilter()
{ 
  var now = new Date();
  let yesterday=new Date(new Date().getTime() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  let last7Days=new Date(new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var data=obj.filter(p => new Date(p.LastSeenDate) <= yesterday && new Date(p.LastSeenDate) >= last3Days);     
}
```

Here `LastSeenDate` is date of our product.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use moment

```
moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25');
```

Here is the link to the doc : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-dst-shifted/

Comment: Not sure, why this was downvoted but It was exactly what I was looking for. Straight forward and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring [joshua k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5200357/joshua-k)'s approach to make it simple

```js
const data = product_data.filter(data => {
  if(!data.ProductHits) {return};
  const [strDate] = Object.keys(data.ProductHits);           
  const date = new Date(strDate);
  return date > new Date('2015-05-01') && date < new Date('2015-08-10')
 });
 console.log(data);
```