# Date Picker filter pipe

Tags: html, angular, angular-pipe, ng-modules

In my app.component.html page, I designed a table that loads data using ngFor, and an input form to take in a date range. I have designed a custom pipe to filter out data outside user inputed date range. I want to to print out all user rows where date of birth is within the selected time frame.

**app.component.html:**

```
    <input type="text" matInput
            id = 'calander'
            ngxDaterangepickerMd
            [locale]="{ applyLabel: 'Okay', format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'}"
            startKey="start"
            endKey="end"
            [(ngModel)]="selected"
            name="daterange"/>
            <button class="ripple"type="submit"></button>

<tr *ngFor="let user of users | myfilter:selected" >
              <td class="tg-0lax" id="tableText">{{ user.FirstName}}</td>
              <td class="tg-0lax" id="tableText">{{ user.LastName}}</td>
              <td class="tg-0lax"><b>{{ user.DoB| date: 'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</b></td>
            </tr>
```

**app-filter.pipe.ts:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter',
    pure: false
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], filter: Object): any {  //1. List to filter, 2. Selected items
        if (!items || !filter) {
            return items;
        }
        return items.filter(item =>
            item.DoB>= filter.start && item.DoB<= filter.end);
    }
}
```

When I run ng build it returns the following error:
*error TS2339: Property 'start' does not exist on type 'Object'.*, and
*error TS2339: Property 'end' does not exist on type 'Object'*

How do I reference data in the ngModule to have it properly work?

Comment: It’s recommend to not use pipes for filtering or sorting, just do the filtering/sorting in the component. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Checkout this.. [How to filter json data by date range in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977724/how-to-filter-json-data-by-date-range-in-javascript)