# the sum for all country in a specific date as object that will be stored in an array for covid-19 data from the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I want to create an array of covid-19 where deaths and cases for a all dates will be stored from the api in react "https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/"

I want to know how can I get data for a specific date in an array where all data for all dates will be stored

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter json data by date range in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977724/how-to-filter-json-data-by-date-range-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. The first option is to try to find out if this API has a specific request for your type of needs. The second is to make an algorithm.

```js
{records} = await <api.request>();
const arr = [];
function findByDate(day){
 records.map((prop)=>{
  if(prop.day === day){
  arr.push(prop);
  }
})
}
findByDate('2');
```